# Passport: fail to initialize MongoStore

Tags: mongodb, passport.js, mongostore

I am trying to follow the example given [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-implement-passport-js-local-authentication-7617a2ef93e8):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
```

but this fails immediately with:

```
ServerMiddleware Error: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

on the third line.

Is MongoStore documented somewhere? Is there a better example/tutorial I should following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is over 2 years old which contains deprecated syntax, you can either downgrade your npm pkg versions, or use the updated syntax:

```
import session from 'express-session'
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'


const app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'foo',
  store: MongoStore.create(options)
}));
```